# Cannot modify Process DACL that I own with my code but Process Hacker can

Tags: c++, security, winapi

I have a process (let's call it *ProcessX*) that runs by default with only `Terminate`, `Synchronize`, and `Query Limited Information` permissions.

When I look at *ProcessX* in Process Hacker, I can see the permission (ACE, Owner, etc). I can see that I'm the owner of *ProcessX*, I can see the 3 limited permissions associated with it (`Terminate`, `Synchronize`, and `Query Limited Information`), and I can even edit the permissions (for instance, set `Full Control` on it).

However, when I run the code below to check the DACL of *ProcessX*, with the same user that owns *ProcessX*, I'm getting an error code 5 (Access Denied) on the `GetSecurityInfo()` function.

Same results with AccessChk and Process Explorer on *ProcessX*.

However, Process Hacker is perfectly able to read the DACL of *ProcessX* and modify it.

I don't understand. How is that possible? Why is my code unable to read the DACL for *ProcessX*?

I've read in MS documents that to read the DACL, I must use `OpenProcess()` with `READ_CONTROL`.

But `READ_CONTROL` is not an available ACE on the process for my user. So, I can't open the process with it (`OpenProcess()` errors if I try, which is logical).

So, I'm the owner of the process, but I can't modify the ACE, but Process Hacker can.

Can anybody help me understand?

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <accctrl.h>
#include <aclapi.h>
#include <winnt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lmcons.h>


DWORD AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor (
    HANDLE pszObjName,          // name of object
    SE_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType,  // type of object
    LPTSTR pszTrustee,          // trustee for new ACE
    TRUSTEE_FORM TrusteeForm,   // format of trustee structure
    DWORD dwAccessRights,       // access mask for new ACE
    ACCESS_MODE AccessMode,     // type of ACE
    DWORD dwInheritance         // inheritance flags for new ACE
) 
{
    DWORD dwRes = 0;
    PACL pOldDACL = NULL, pNewDACL = NULL;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;

    if (NULL == pszObjName) 
        return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    //retrieve user
    char username[UNLEN+1];
    DWORD username_len = UNLEN+1;
    GetUserName(username, &username_len);
    printf(username);

    // Get a pointer to the existing DACL.

    dwRes = GetSecurityInfo(pszObjName, ObjectType, 
          DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
          NULL, NULL, &pOldDACL, NULL, &pSD);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes) {
        printf( "GetSecurityInfo Error %u\n", dwRes );
        goto Cleanup; 
    }  

    // Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for the new ACE. 

    ZeroMemory(&ea, sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
    ea.grfAccessPermissions = dwAccessRights;
    ea.grfAccessMode = AccessMode;
    ea.grfInheritance= dwInheritance;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TrusteeForm;
    ea.Trustee.ptstrName = pszTrustee;

    // Create a new ACL that merges the new ACE
    // into the existing DACL.

    dwRes = SetEntriesInAcl(1, &ea, pOldDACL, &pNewDACL);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes)  {
        printf( "SetEntriesInAcl Error %u\n", dwRes );
        goto Cleanup; 
    }  

    // Attach the new ACL as the object's DACL.

    dwRes = SetSecurityInfo(pszObjName, ObjectType, 
          DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
          NULL, NULL, pNewDACL, NULL);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes)  {
        printf( "SetSecurityInfo Error %u\n", dwRes );
        goto Cleanup; 
    }  

    Cleanup:

        if(pSD != NULL) 
            LocalFree((HLOCAL) pSD); 
        if(pNewDACL != NULL) 
            LocalFree((HLOCAL) pNewDACL); 

        return dwRes;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int pid = atoi(argv[1]);
  printf("[+] Ensuring we have the proper privs....\n");
  HANDLE self = OpenProcess(
  PROCESS_TERMINATE | PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION | SYNCHRONIZE,
  FALSE, (DWORD) pid);
  if(self != NULL){
    printf("process open !\n"); 
    AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor(self, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, (LPSTR)"S-1-5-21-BLABLALEAKBLALBLA",TRUSTEE_IS_SID, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, GRANT_ACCESS, 0);
  }
  else{
      printf("error in opening of the process\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "READ_CONTROL is not an available ACE on my process for my user"?  Are you getting a compile-time error?  A run-time error?  What is the error message?

Comment: Also, the docs mention that to use READ_CONTROL, "you must request the ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY access right".  Did you do that?.  Read this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/sacl-access-right

Comment: ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY is needed with READ_CONTROL to read SACL not DACL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/standard-access-rights

Comment: As far as I'm concerned， you could try to use [SetNamedSecurityInfoA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setnamedsecurityinfoa).If the discretionary access control list (DACL) of the object is being set, the calling process must have either WRITE_DAC permission or be the owner of the object. You could refer to the Doc:[Modifying the ACLs of an Object in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/modifying-the-acls-of-an-object-in-c--)

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Too me SetNamed*  is not compatible with process. 


According to the documentation "his can be the name of a local or remote file or directory on an NTFS file system, network share, registry key, semaphore, event, mutex, file mapping, or waitable timer." 


What do you mean the calling process must be owner of the object ? In my case, The process with the DACL I want to read is running before the execution of the reader process. 


However, the process that want to read the DACL and the target process runs with on the same user with the same integrity level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved !

I've assumed that `READ_CONTROL` will be refused because it wasn't available on the DACL of the running process.

Turns out, when you own an object, you have implicit `READ_CONTROL` and `WRITE_DAC` permission on it, even if zero ACE are set on the object for the user owning it.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <accctrl.h>
#include <aclapi.h>
#include <winnt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lmcons.h>



DWORD AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor (
    HANDLE pszObjName,          // name of object
    SE_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType,  // type of object
    LPTSTR pszTrustee,          // trustee for new ACE
    TRUSTEE_FORM TrusteeForm,   // format of trustee structure
    DWORD dwAccessRights,       // access mask for new ACE
    ACCESS_MODE AccessMode,     // type of ACE
    DWORD dwInheritance         // inheritance flags for new ACE
) 
{
    DWORD dwRes = 0;
    PACL pOldDACL = NULL, pNewDACL = NULL;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;

    if (NULL == pszObjName) 
        return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;


    // Get a pointer to the existing DACL.

    dwRes = GetSecurityInfo(pszObjName, ObjectType, 
          DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
          NULL, NULL, &pOldDACL, NULL, &pSD);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes) {
        printf( "GetSecurityInfo Error %u\n", dwRes );
        goto Cleanup; 
    }  

    // Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for the new ACE. 

    ZeroMemory(&ea, sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
    ea.grfAccessPermissions = dwAccessRights;
    ea.grfAccessMode = AccessMode;
    ea.grfInheritance= dwInheritance;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TrusteeForm;
    ea.Trustee.ptstrName = pszTrustee;

    // Create a new ACL that merges the new ACE
    // into the existing DACL.

    dwRes = SetEntriesInAcl(1, &ea, pOldDACL, &pNewDACL);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes)  {
        printf( "SetEntriesInAcl Error %u\n", dwRes );
        goto Cleanup; 
    }else{
      printf("SetEntriesAcl SUCCESS !\n");
    }  

    // Attach the new ACL as the object's DACL.

    dwRes = SetSecurityInfo(pszObjName, ObjectType, 
          DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
          NULL, NULL, pNewDACL, NULL);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes)  {
        printf( "SetSecurityInfo Error %u\n", dwRes );
        goto Cleanup; 
    }else{
      printf("SetSecurityInfo SUCCESS \n");
    }  

    Cleanup:

        if(pSD != NULL) 
            LocalFree((HLOCAL) pSD); 
        if(pNewDACL != NULL) 
            LocalFree((HLOCAL) pNewDACL); 

        return dwRes;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int pid = atoi(argv[1]);
  DWORD dwRes = 0;

  char username[UNLEN+1];
  DWORD username_len = UNLEN+1;
  GetUserName(username, &username_len);

  HANDLE self = OpenProcess(READ_CONTROL | WRITE_DAC, FALSE, (DWORD) pid);
  if(self != NULL){
    printf("process open !\n"); 
    AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor(self, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, (LPSTR)username,TRUSTEE_IS_NAME, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, GRANT_ACCESS, 0);
  }
  else{
      dwRes = GetLastError();
      printf("error in opening of the process. Code %u \n", dwRes);
  }
}
```

Comment: Earlier you wrote "(OpenProcess() errors if I try [to open with READ_CONTROL], which is logical)." But now it works. What changed?

Comment: I was trying to use `READ_CONTROL` with unauthorized ACE like `PROCESS_VM_WRITE`, `PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD` etc.

Example : 

```OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD|PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_OPERATION|PROCESS_VM_READ|PROCESS_VM_WRITE|READ_CONTROL,FALSE, (DWORD) pid);```

Now, I'm opening the process with the existing authorized ACE **and** `READ_CONTROL` (and `WRITE DAC` to be able to write the new DAC).

However, the same code can also work in my case with just `READ_CONTROL` and `WRITE_DAC` permissions. 

`OpenProcess(READ_CONTROL|WRITE_DAC,FALSE, (DWORD) pid);`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. The owner of an object always has `READ_CONTROL` and `WRITE_DAC` even if not listed in the security descriptor. However, the other stuff must still be granted.

Comment: It was my mistake in the comprehension of DACL. I didn't know that owner has implicit `READ_CONTROL` and `WRITE_DAC` even if not listed...